# Cell colour condition loop.Object required error

Tags: vba, colors, conditional-statements, do-while

I am trying to create two arrays: one having the row numbers of orange cells and the other with the row numbers of blue cells. I've been trying to debug this code for a while but it is giving me the error: "Compile error: Object required"; whilst highlighting in yellow the first line of the function: "Function ArrayOrangeBlue()". I'm new to VBA and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in the syntax.

Do you have any feedback please?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Clicked()
    ArrayOrangeBlue
End Sub

Function ArrayOrangeBlue()

Dim i As Integer    'row number'
Dim j As Integer    'orange counter'
Dim k As Integer    'blue counter'

Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim blue(1 To 1000) As Double
Dim orange(1 To 1000) As Double

'Starting Row'
Set i = 10

'Initialize orange and blue counters to 1'
Set j = 1
Set k = 1

Set l = 10
Set m = 10


'Loop until Row 1000'
Do While i <= 1000

'Dim cell As Range

'Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

    'If cell colour is Orange- note absolute row number (i) in array: orange'
    If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 9420794 Then

        orange(j) = i
        Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(l, 15) = i
        j = j + 1
        l = l + 1
        'MsgBox ("This one is Orange")

    Else

        'If cell colour is Blue- note absolute row number (i) in array: blue'
        If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 13995347 Then

        blue(k) = i
        Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(m, 16) = i
        k = k + 1
        m = m + 1
        'MsgBox ("This one is Blue")

        End If

    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop


End Function
```

Comment: Omit `set` from lines containing variable assignment lines like `set j=1`

Answer (score 0):

so finally I managed to resolve my code to find and note cells with certain colours.

here the code stores the row numbers of the Orange cells in the array orange() and in column 1 of array Arr() and Blue cells in the array blue() and in column 2 of array Arr().

I removed the "Set" command when initialising the variables.

However, more critically, I was required to specify the sheet in each If statement.

I hope this helps someone else.

```
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ArrayOrangeBlue Function
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'

Dim i As Integer    ' row number '
Dim j As Integer    ' orange counter '
Dim k As Integer    ' blue counter '

Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim blue(1 To 50) As Double
Dim orange(1 To 50) As Double
Dim green As Double


' Starting Row '

i = 10

' Initialize orange and blue counters to 1 '

j = 1
k = 1



l = 10
m = 10
Dim Arr(100, 2) As Double

' Loop until Row 1000 '

Do While i <= 1000


''''' If cell colour is Orange- note absolute row number (i) in array: orange '

If Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 9420794 Then

    orange(j) = i
    Arr(j, 1) = i


    j = j + 1

Else

''''''''' If cell colour is Blue- note absolute row number (i) in array: blue '

    If Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 13995347 Then

    blue(k) = i
    Arr(k, 2) = i


    k = k + 1

    Else

''''''''''''' If cell colour is Gren- store the absolute row number (i) in: green '

        If Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 5296274 Then

        Arr(j, 1) = i
        green = i

        End If
    End If
End If

i = i + 1
Loop
```